# How to iterate a texture more times?

Tags: materials

I added material (tiles on floor) into my object and after that it looks like below

[image: Image that rendered my object]

No of tiles are added automatically when I adding material. But I need to add more tiles(small tiles). Is there any way to do it in properties? 
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cycles you can do this by using the Mapping Node and adjusting the Scale values.

The higher the Scale values, the more times your texture will repeat within the texture space.

[image]

If using Blender Render you can change the scale of the texture here:

[image: Texture Scale settings]

If this will be for a game you may consider [scaling the UV Layout instead.](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/scaling-materials-and-resizing-texture-uvw-maps-on-models.php)